# confusing behavior of javascript

Tags: javascript

I just met with this piece of code,  and totally lost what happen at second console line.

```js
if ("test") {
    console.log("test" == false)
    console.log("test" == true)  // why this one is false ?
}
```

How this could have same result, it is neither true nor false?

Comment: checkout this documentation --> http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/208/comparison-operations/2110/abstract-equality-inequality-and-type-conversion#t=201612050643511492204

Comment: Why is `"test"` being neither `true` nor `false` surprising? A car is neither an apple, nor a banana; I don't see anything strange here.